# How can I display a SafeUrl or a SafeResourceUrl?

Tags: angular

I'm loading a trusted URL into an iframe which works fine. I also want to display that URL as a string on the page. I've tried `<div>{{url}}</div>` but it displays:

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding: /my/resource/path.html (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

I also tried using `<div [ngModel]="url"></div>`, but got

> Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

How can I display it?

Comment: Check out my answer. I belive `DomSanitizer` is what you are looking for here. Cheers! ;)

Comment: @adamdport What did you end up doing for this type of thing? I saw your comment below about creating a separate var for the url string, which is what I was thinking, too. Perhaps I'll make it protected so it has some differentiation.

Comment: I used a separate variable. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in another way:

```
<iframe #foo [src]="contentUrl"></iframe>
<p>{{ foo.src }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The error says use [property] binding - it means [innerHTML] for html
2. You want to display this value as html (not url or resource) - use bypassSecurityTrustHtml

   ```
    @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       <div [innerHTML]="url"><div>
     `
    })
   export class App {

     dangerousVideoUrl = "href='&#x3000;javascript:alert(1)'";

     constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
       this.url =
       this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.dangerousVideoUrl);
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: But I need it to be a `SafeResourceUrl` for use in my iframe. I can certainly make a separate variable from the string that I pass into `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: sorry, i did not get because all errors in your questions show html binding. i would make it work first and after that implement pipe for cleaner solution. bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl should work for iframes

Comment: It DOES work for iframes. But I want to also display its value in HTML. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: @adamdport did you find a solution to this? how did you set the targetOrigin? I'm trying to use the postMessage API and want to extract targetOrigin from the destination URL

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `@Pipe` for using this in all your App and with `DomSanitizer` for sanitizing the URL and bypass XSS security.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeUrl',
    pure: false
})
export class AsString implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(value: string, args?: any): any {            
        return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div>{{url | sanitizeUrl}}</div>
```

Comment: "value.string is not a function". `value` is of type `SafeResourceUrlImpl`. It has a `toString()` method, but that returns "SafeValue must use [property]=binding:  /my/resource/path.html (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

Comment: @adamdport Check my answer. You have to use `DomSanitizer`.

Comment: It still displays the "SafeValue must use [property]=binding" message. I set a breakpoint to verify that it is getting into my pipe. @SrAxi

Comment: Is it possible to use bypassSecurityTrustUrl with a post? I can't find any examples on that.